# Not able to get Access Token using Authorization code in Spring Social [Google]

Tags: java, android, google-api, spring-boot

I am getting Authorization code via Android application but When I am using below mentioned code to get access token I am getting `org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request`.

```
accessToken = googleConnectionFactory.getOAuthOperations().authenticateClient(code).getAccessToken();
```

I have also gone through various posts regarding the same and tried those as well but error was the same.

Thanks.